# SQL Server trigger - modify the id column

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

After hours of googling and search here , I am able to create this trigger; This trigger works well, and keeps the two tables synced in 2 different tables. (I am not worried about batched operations, that wouldn't happen). The only issue is that If the USER_ID is modified (that is primary key), it does not gets updated in 2nd table); I am not able to get the 'UPDATE' part right. What am I doing wrong?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [u].[SyncUsers] 
   ON  [u].[USERS] 
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 

BEGIN

    IF (@@rowcount = 0) RETURN;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- deleted data
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) 
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM ERP_DB.u.USERS WHERE USER_ID = 
            (SELECT USER_ID FROM deleted);
            RETURN;
        END
    ELSE 
        BEGIN

            -- inserted data
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
                BEGIN           
                    INSERT INTO ERP_DB.u.USERS(USER_ID, USER_NAME , DISPLAY_NAME , EMP_ID , DEPARTMENT_ID)  SELECT USER_ID, USER_NAME , DISPLAY_NAME , EMP_ID , DEPARTMENT_ID FROM inserted;
                    RETURN;
                END

            -- updated data
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE UU
                        SET UU.USER_ID = i.USER_ID,
                            UU.USER_NAME = i.USER_NAME ,
                            UU.DISPLAY_NAME = i.DISPLAY_NAME ,
                            UU.DEPARTMENT_ID = i.DEPARTMENT_ID ,
                            UU.EMP_ID = i.EMP_ID 

                            FROM ERP_DB.u.USERS AS UU
                INNER JOIN Inserted AS i ON UU.USER_ID = i.USER_ID

            RETURN;
        END 
    END -- updated data
    END
END
```

Comment: Having a trigger accessing resources outside of its own database is usually a very bad idea. It's essentially tying two databases together intimately - you can no longer say, take one database offline without crippling the other one. Why is `USERS` in `ERP_DB` not just a view back into your current database?

Comment: Actually I've a separate database for Users Maintenance, policies, roles etc, that is common for all applications (having their own separate databases) running inside the organization. And as I can not create a referential integrity constraint between 2 database, the only solution was to create a users table in each database, and create a trigger to sync them with users database.

Comment: The cure is worse than the disease. I'd *seriously* recommend dropping your requirement for a FK back to the users table in each client application rather than tying all of your databases together like this.

Comment: So what is the cure then? if the databases for all applications are merged then this will create a single large database. I need FK constraint, as to log which entry was done by which user. Currently no FK are defined yet. I just started on thinking that this can be done by creating a users table in each for refrential integrity and trigger can be used to sync them. I am not worried about offline database though. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it doesn't, because the PK of the table was changed. The value of `user_id` column in `inserted` pseudotable is different from the one in the `UU` table. You need the value from deleted table to match the `user_id` column, and everything else from `inserted`. But the problem is that there is no way to match `inserted` and `deleted` tables any more, when the PK was changed. A mess.

If it's always a single-row update, you might get away with it, using a cross join between UU and `inserted` and a `WHERE UU.user_id = (SELECT user_id from deleted)' in the update statement.

Mutch better -- disallow the PK update altogether. After all, it's not the same row any more if the PK's changed.

Answer (score 1):

**You should never be modifying Primary Key.**

If it is some thing that can be **modified** , it **can not be a primary key**.

Primary key should generally be `Auto Generated` and must be **read only**.

So, what you are assuming might happen is wrong or either your database design is wrong.

If primary key is `editable`, you can  not ensure `uniqueness` which **violates** prime quality of Primary Key

Hope this helps..

Comment: Actually I don't like Auto Generated IDs, that troubles me in many cases. So can I make a non auto generated column as readonly?

Comment: That can do the job , but you have to make sure no duplications